# Synchronising self-blinking LEDs (for fun)

Tags: led, synchronization, blink

I think most here are familiar with [Big Clive's super computer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bI_zgZz-V40), or [one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YS3CIC0KyME) of [the](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1epn-IqHZgo) many [variations](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T4jA6mE98dI) (and for those who aren't: the links will explain/demonstrate).

This effect 'works' because the timing of the LEDs isn't super precise of course. But this got me wondering; would there be a way to have them fall in sync as [Mythbusters once showed with metronomes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e-c6S6SdkPo) like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5v5eBf2KwF8)?

I know you could just solder 'normal' LEDs to a PCB and use some microcontroller or something to achieve the effect, but where's the fun in that? I'm curious if there's a way to 'nudge' the 'clock' of such a self-blinking LED slightly. Preferably by an analogue feedback loop as with the metronomes; measuring wether a LED is on/off and then using some microcontroller to nudge the timing isn't as much fun.

Ideally the board would run in 'normal' mode (the LEDs flickering randomly) and by throwing a switch the feedback loop is enabled and the LEDs slowly start falling in sync. I am a beginner in electronics *at best* so I have no clue where to start but I can follow explanations and *maybe* even turn it into a prototype.

Edit: What a coincidence; Veritasium [published a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t-_VPRCtiUg) on the subject an hour ago, about, what, 16 hours after I posted this.

Edit (long time later): [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EKnG7z4mGaE) (from 0:00 to 3:47) also seems to hint at what is at the root of my question.

Comment: Never heard of it.

Comment: I'm saying it so that you won't be disappointed by the lack of answers (in case that happens).

Comment: I have to admit I've never heard of it either so your statement seems off. With regard to the question an interesting approach might be to try and "read" the LED prior to illuminating it to detect if another adjacent LED is illuminated. To some extent LEDs from a given batch may be used as "Photodiodes", you could potentially use this to increment/decrement a processor driven timing loop to bring a "slaved" LED into sync.

Comment: The video shows sync'd fireflies that I have never seen. I assume you want the LEDs to be sync'd WIRELESSLY? Then each LED circuit needs a light detector and bright light flashes the sync pulses. Or each LED circuit has a radio detector and a radio transmitter sends sync signals.

Comment: I was 'aiming for' / looking for a way to sync the LED's without any (or a lot of) extra components but more like the metronomes do by something they have in common like the ground plane (which doesn't work obviously, since they are sharing the ground plane already). Just looking for a 'phenomenon' that may get them in sync like the metronomes "magically" (note the quotes) fall in sync.

Answer (score 2):

Blinking LEDs use a small CMOS chip that has an RC oscillator on it.

The oscillation frequency is undoubtedly somewhat affected by the voltage, but there is no guarantee it's "pullable" enough to synchronize two oscillators.

If I was going to spend an afternoon doing this, I'd first make measurements to ensure it's feasible (frequency vs. voltage measurements).

Then I'd use comparators to pull an  on/off signal from the LED currents and then feed that to a phase comparator (eg. '[4046](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4046b.pdf?ts=1617184806663&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FCD4046B%253Futm_source%253Dsupplyframe%2526utm_medium%253DSEP%2526utm_campaign%253Dnot_alldatasheet%2526DCM%253Dyes%2526dclid%253DCLHGwO2i2u8CFfHVEQgdyRsKyg)), the analog comparator output could drive a see-saw voltage amplifier to feed the LEDs.

The low-pass filter time constant would have to be extremely long. It would almost surely be better to use digital means, but that sounds more like work than fun.

Very few datasheets show the variation of blink frequency with voltage/temperature but an old Vishay one ( TLBR5410 ) does.

[image]

Considering the tolerance is 1.3 to 5.2 Hz at room temperature, there are no guarantees. [Kingbright](https://www.kingbrightusa.com/images/catalog/SPEC/WP56BID.pdf) flashing LEDs have more like a 2:1 tolerance (1.5 to 3Hz at room temperature), but no information at all on variations with voltage or temperature.

Answer (score 0):

An optical sensor could sync up to a master or nearby ones also doing the same otherwise off the master or the nearest one. Then they all sync up on the 1st beat with a 1 shot time out being something by choice.

Comment: I was more thinking along the lines of adding some transistors, resistors, capacitors or whathaveyou's to decrease/increase voltage/current and try to affect the blinking that way by 'slowing down' or 'speeding up' the timing relative to the others / closest neighbours.

Comment: @RobIII Actually, yes. There's a way for that. I recommend that you look up the MSP430 timer system. In particular, how you can incrementally adjust its DCO timing system. Each MCU would be uncalibrated to start, so even with the same settings they wouldn't meet each others' timing because of their inherent manufacturing variations. (They do include calibration values. But you can ignore those.) Once they start up, they could be arranged to only see nearby units and attempt to calibrate (adjust) their DCOs in a way that you design (not instantly but gradually.) Your idea is really good.

Comment: @RobIII It's actually not dissimilar to how your (and my) heart works. There are myocytes in the sinoatrial node that observe each other firing and learn to coordinate that process together. There are also certain kinds of fireflies that can synchronize over distances of miles, so that they all pulse together. It's a field of study and VERY interesting. In the heart, if these cells get out of sync, it's a potentially serious problem and that's when an AED can help by re-syncing the cells back up.

Comment: DEFIB LEDs , just following nature! Without the QRST wave, except you might be able to use the LEDs with an op amp or buffered 4000 series hex amp to sense the light as a 1000 gain amp. And same as 1 shots and 74HCxx CMOS as drivers. But only If they are the brightest luminent intensity around. But one false triggered LED then ya gotta bring out the AED flashlight. Or let the pleisochronous activity come back to normal cardiac rhythm.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plesiochronous_digital_hierarchy

Answer (score 0):

That depends on how the blink is done… just for fun, doing 100% analog, assuming a relaxation oscillator blinker (like a 555 or a cross transistor astable):

- Get a way to detect the led lighting up. The real old way would be a CdS or a photomultiplier (that would be hardcore). Or just cheat picking the drive signal from the LED.
- Compare it with the current state of the driven LED. That's not simple using discrete transistors (need many of them!). Cheat with some logic gate.
- When not in sync, use the output to fill-up/discharge the relaxation capacitor (depending on your oscillator type) so it goes faster or slower.

Ooops. I just described a PLL with a type I detector. Not my fault, that's the analog way to sync up oscillators (quite a cornerstone of modern technology, too)

Answer (score 0):

The analogy of the mechanical link is the electrical connection. Using a photodetector is not the same, as the intensity drops with distance. Anyway you should think about using two sources/detectors one for each half cycle, like visible blue and infrared.

The most similar behavior you could get with an apparatus that is bi-directional, i.e. it has the ability to transfer power and receive it at the same time, so the interaction is made possible. The transverse EM wave, like visible light doesn't have it.

I think it could be possible using self resonant VLF LC transmitter, like a ferrite  coil transmitter, but it would also drop the strength with distance squared. The H field would act like a link, where the surrounding fields could alter the phase in transmitting coil.

EDIT:

Another approach that comes into my mind is to use a HF square wave to turn on the LED, while blank to detect light from other objects. When in phase it should not detect any light, same as working alone. If visible and IR are both used - cycling, then you can extract the HF carrier from both and use a [ADPLL](http://dangerousprototypes.com/blog/2014/08/13/implementing-an-all-digital-phase-locked-loop/) to sync.

Moreover, you could use PWM to modulate sin/cos on visible/IR led, then sample from detectors when blank and compute the phase angle with atan2(), the gains from receiving opamps should match, so that the amplified signal is 100% if emitting is 100%. To go further, each LED can also work as detector, but very weakly.